# Spring OAuth2 not giving refresh token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am running a OAuth Provider using Spring and "password" grant type.

Running this (provider is on port 8080):

```
curl -u "app:appclientsecret" "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token" --data "grant_type=password&username=marissa&password=koala"
```

returns:

```
{"access_token":"56da4d2b-7e66-483e-b88d-c1a58ee5a453","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"read"}
```

For some reason there is no refresh token. I know according to the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.3), the refresh token is optional; is there some way to enable it that I missed?

For reference, here is my provider code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Provider {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.setProperty("server.port", "8080");

        SpringApplication.run(Provider.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final UserStoreType type = UserStoreType.IN_MEMORY;

        enum UserStoreType {
            IN_MEMORY,
        }

        @Autowired
        public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            switch(type) {
                case IN_MEMORY:
                    System.err.println("Setting up user creds..");

                    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                            .withUser("marissa").password("koala").roles("USER")
                            .and()
                            .withUser("admin").password("topsecret").roles("USER", "ADMIN");

                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    static class OAuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(new InMemoryTokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("resource-serv")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds("my-resource")
                    .secret("secret123")
                    .and()
                    .withClient("app")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds("my-resource")
                    .secret("appclientsecret");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The client needs authorizedGrantType "refresh_token".

Try this

```
  @Override
            public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                clients.inMemory()
                        .withClient("resource-serv")
                        .scopes("read")
                        .resourceIds("my-resource")
                        .secret("secret123")
                        .and()
                        .withClient("app")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "refresh_token")
                        .scopes("read")
                        .resourceIds("my-resource")
                        .secret("appclientsecret");
            }
```

Comment: Fixed it. I just had to add `tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);` to my token services.

Comment: As we may see the evaluation at https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/blob/main/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java#L365